# How to Match styling of JQuery Mobile Header Button in Body?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, button

On **[this page](http://www.alta-publishing.com/m/dermbar/about.htm)**, there's a Home button in the header. I'd like to match that exact styling in the Home button you see at the bottom of the page. The JQM framework is applying some mix of classes in the header button, but I can't seem to figure out how to apply that style so that the bottom button matches.

For example, the font size and the button itself are larger in the bottom button. I don't want to put the bottom button in a footer because there's already a fixed footer, and I don't want to draw too much attention, should be just a simple button to return to the home page.  Can anyone help with this?  Thanks!

Comment: They seem the same to me... Except that one is larger

Comment: The top button is getting some styles based on the wrapper div it's in. It would be simpler to just apply the styles to the bottom button rather than wrapping it in the necessary parent elements and adding all of those classes

Comment: Thanks Joshua, I've attempted to do that but the button doesn't change at all. Either I'm grabbing the wrong styles from Firebug or I'm applying them to the wrong element. Can someone post a solution with code?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, add an id to the second button and add these styles

```
#second-button
{
    font-size: 12.5px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 11px;
```

For the anchor tag surrounding the second button

```
#second-button-a
{
    box-shadow: box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

There you go bro. I used firebug to inspect the 2 elements and check the differences. I would strongly advise installing firebug (A firefox plugin). It's super useful for frontend web development for anything involving html, css and javascript. All the best.

Comment: +1 good answer. Personally i prefer included [Page Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector), imo it's much simpler to use than Firebug. Greetings

Comment: Haven't tried that @Stano . Firebug satisfies all my needs.. But you never know the benefits something else until you come across it. Will definitely check it out, thanks.

Comment: @Joshua: Thanks for the code. You're reading these styles right out of Firebug? I guess I need to come up to speed -- not clear on where to go in the Firebug interface to know precisely which styles are being used.

Comment: @user2736184 Please do select the answer as the correct question answer

Comment: @JoshuaKissoon  Agreed, these are the changes needed, but I'm not able to successfully apply them. the following has no effect. Is some type of compound selector required? 

#bottomhome {
    font-size: 12.5px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 11px; 
}

<a id="bottomhome" href="/m/dermbar/index.htm" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-ajax="false">Home</a>